# To GET Names of days between two days in mysql

Tags: java, mysql, sql

Is there any method in MySql which can return the name of days between two dates. For example `06/11/207` is start date and `12/11/2017` is end  date then I need to get the output as:

> monday,tuesday,wednesday,thursday,friday,saturday,sunday

Comment: MySQL is for the storage and retrieval of data. Other tasks are generally best resolved in application code

Answer (score 0):

you can try this :

you can take F_TABLE_NUMBER_RANGE function from this link:

http://www.sqlteam.com/forums/topic.asp?TOPIC_ID=47685

```
declare @start_date     datetime
declare @end_date       datetime
declare @days           int

select @start_date  = '06/11/2017'
select @end_date    = '12/11/2017'

select @days = datediff(dd,@start_date,@end_date) +1

select
    [Date]      = dateadd(dd,number-1,@start_date),
    [Day of Week]   = datename(weekday,dateadd(dd,number-1,@start_date))
from
    dbo.F_TABLE_NUMBER_RANGE( 1, @days )
order by
    number
```

This I have tried and working for me cheers !

Comment: Not in MySQL you haven’t

Comment: Ahhh then why he tagged it with sql :(

Comment: 'sql' refers to all structured query languages. Perhaps you're thinking of sql-server/m$sql.

Answer (score 0):

## tl;dr

Use Java. Auto-localize.

```
myResultSet.getObject( … , LocalDate.class )   // Retrieve a `LocalDate` object from your database.
    .getDayOfWeek()                            // Fetch the `DayOfWeek` object appropriate for this date. Ex: DayOfWeek.MONDAY
    .getDisplayName(                           // Generate a String of the name of day-of-week.
        TextStyle.FULL ,                       // How long or abbreviated?
        Locale.US                              // Or Locale.CANADA_FRENCH, etc.
    )
```

> Monday

## Details

Generally best to do such transformations within your app rather than SQL, IMHO.

Java has an industry-leading date-time framework now in Java 8 and later, the *java.time* classes.

The [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) class represents a date-only value without time-of-day and without time zone.

With JDBC 4.2 and later, you can directly exchange *java.time* objects with your database.

```
LocalDate localDate = myResultSet.getObject( … , LocalDate.class ) ;  // Retrieval.
myPreparedStatement.setObject( … , localDate ) ; // Insert/Update.
```

The [`DayOfWeek`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/DayOfWeek.html) enum offers seven existing objects, one for each day of the week. Use the `getDisplayName` method to generate an automatically localized name for the day-of-week.

```
DayOfWeek dow = localDate.getDayOfWeek() ;
String output = dow.getDisplayName( TextStyle.FULL , Locale.CANADA_FRENCH ) ;
```

> lundi

Or, US English:

```
DayOfWeek dow = localDate.getDayOfWeek() ;
String output = dow.getDisplayName( TextStyle.FULL , Locale.US ) ;
```

> Monday

Compare `LocalDate` objects with `isBefore` and `isAfter` and other methods. Loop each date incrementally by calling `LocalDate::plusDays`.

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the java.time classes.
  - For earlier Android, the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).